# How to Trigger an event when usb is plugged

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have developed a device driver which will create a virtual com port whenever my embedded device is connected to the USB port of the laptop.

Now I need to create an Auto Dial-Up or new network connection with the virtual com port created whenever the device gets plugged into the laptop.

1. So I have to trigger an event upon USB connection detection
2. The triggered event should create an auto dial up connection with the vitual port created(eg:COM11).

Steps to create a New Auto Dial Up connection:

1. Click on the Windows “Start” button.
2. Click on “Control Panel”.
3. Click on “Network connections”.
4. Click on “Create a new connection”.
5. Select the option “Set up an advanced connection”.
6. Select the option    “Connect directly to another computer”.
7. Select the “Guest” option.   Give a name to the USB network connection (e.g. “Connection Name”).
8. **Select the last COM port created on the PC corresponding to    “Communications Port (COM X)”**.
9. Select the option “All users”.
10. Click  on “Add a shortcut to this connection to my desktop”, then “ok”.

What are the ways I can achieve an auto dial up connection?

The above can be done in any programming language, preferabally "C/C++", Since I know only those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve dialup connections using the RasDial API functions. See this [project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2813/Creating-Dialup-Connections) for a guide. You can create a window, register it using [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and listen for WM_DEVICECHANGE. You can see [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14500/Detecting-Hardware-Insertion-and-or-Removal) too for an example. Good Luck