# Trigger an exe once My device is connected via USB

Tags: c++, c, winapi, usb, device-driver

Once my embedded device is connected to USB port of my PC, it should trigger an exe as an event. How can I achieve this??

Should I create a service to keep monitoring the USB connector bus or is there any default API's available in Windows to achieve this??

thanks.

Comment: In what context should that EXE run? Current interactively logged-in user? A service would be fairly easy but runs under a predefined account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Trigger an event when usb is plugged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259805/how-to-trigger-an-event-when-usb-is-plugged)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple exe which is started on connect is not possible. But you can write a service or user mode application which listens for device arrival events. [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is sent to all ([registered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) applications with a device interface guid which represents which device is plugged in. You can then use this id with the setupapi to see if its your device.

On receiving that event, you can then start your executable.

Comment: The sample from this thread does exactly this http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/32/164968.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of Windows it might be possible with a [workaround](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/autorun-usb-flash-drive.htm) using a AutoRun.inf file in the root folder of a USB drive. For security reasons this is by default turned off, and in Windows 7 not allowed at all.

To achieve the same effect in a more robust way, you need to create a service that monitors whether your device is connected or not (e.g. iTunesHelper that monitors for connected Apple devices).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. I am wondering how windows autoplay works as soon the USB memory device is inserted and also how windows calls "New Hardware wizard" if no drivers found inside, in another sense the OS will look for the corresponding driver inside the OS for the plugged USB device. Is it possible to use any other windows api(Setup Api) by considering the above points?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of my knowledge I am afraid

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is probably a trivial [UMDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463294) driver. That's basically a small COM component called when your device is connected.