# Can I use the win32 Setup API to detect when USB devices have been plugged-in or unplugged?

Tags: windows, driver, wdk

I'm looking through the references at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376947(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Setup API reference) and [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549791(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (driver Setup API reference) and I don't see a function that would let me register a function that would get called when a particular device/hardwareID/driver key/ or whatever appears.

Anyone know how I would go about this? Ideally I'd like to do this detection in user-space, but if necessary I could work things around detecting this in kernel-space.

Comment: [RegisterDeviceNotification](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=RegisterDeviceNotification)

Comment: Thank you! Post this as an answer and I'll happily grant stackoverflow karma.

Comment: Duplicate [a dozen times over](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwin32%5D+detect+usb+plugged).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Trigger an event when usb is plugged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259805/how-to-trigger-an-event-when-usb-is-plugged)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For notifications that are commonly of interest (e.g. a new disk volume has been plugged-in) Windows automatically broadcasts the [`WM_DEVICECHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to all top-level Windows.  You do not need to register for it.

For notifications that are not delivered automatically you can use [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to request them.